# How to tell if the macOS Catalina install file was deleted once installation was complete?

Tags: macos, catalina

I want to make sure it's not sitting around somewhere taking up disk space.  In the past Apple has put installer files in the Applications folder, but I'm not sure if that is still the case.

Answer (score 1):

> In the past Apple has put installer files in the Applications folder

`/Applications` is still where the installer is placed after downloading.